# Running 12 V water valve from 18650

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell, lithium-ion

I am looking for a suitable solution for my challenge:
I want to run a 12 V [water valve](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33019875310.html) (0.5 A current) with Li-ion 3.7 V - 4.2 V batteries while being able to charge these from a 5 V solar panel (or USB).
Two solutions came to my mind:

1. Connect the batteries in parallel (resulting in a 3.7 V), boost to 12 V to run the valve and charge with an ordinary 1S charger.
2. Connect in series (3S coming at ~12 V) and somehow boost from 5 V to 3S charging voltage and charge with a BMS+Battery charger the 3S pack.

I would love your suggestions on what is the best approach to this problem (energy efficiency, product availability)

Comment: Please note that a BMS is not a lithium charger and a boost converter is not a charger either, so do not boost the voltage and feed that to a lithium battery and expect it to be safe just because there is a BMS. Also, you did not ask a question.

Comment: which valve do you intend to use? How do intend to control it?

Comment: Your water solenoid valve needs 12V nominal to pull in .Will it hold on 3VDC ,?

Comment: @Autistic - No, 12v is needed